# how to use a property from a class to another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a model class like this

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class SpecificCategoryJSON {

var _product_id: Int?
var _product_title: String?
var _product_sku: String?
var _product_image: URL?

init(items: JSON){

    self._product_id = items["product_id"].int
    self._product_title = items["product_title"].stringValue
    self._product_sku = items["product_sku"].stringValue
    let post_imgAA = items["product_image"].arrayValue
    for itemsIMG in post_imgAA {
        self._product_image = itemsIMG["guid"].URL
    }

}
var product_id: Int {
    if _product_id == nil {
        _product_id = 0
    }
    return _product_id!
}

var product_title: String {
    if _product_title == nil {
        _product_title = ""
    }
    return _product_title!
}

var product_sku: String {
    if _product_sku == nil {
        _product_sku = ""
    }
    return _product_sku!
}

var product_image: URL {
    if _product_image == nil {
        let myURL = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-hi.png"
        let noImage: URL = URL(string: myURL)!
        _product_image = noImage
    }
    return _product_image!
   }

  }
```

I want to use the **product_id** to send as a parameter to make a **POST** request using **Alamofire** . Here is the **POST** request where I have kept the **product_id** static .

```
    class ProductDetailsManager {

    //........
    func printPublicGists() -> Void {

    let url: String = "http://xxx/get_product_informations/"
    let parameter = ["product_id": 33]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
     .responseJSON { (response) in

        guard response.result.error == nil else {
           print(response.result.error!)
           return
        }

        guard let value = response.result.value else {
            print("no product to show")
            return
        }

        print(value)

    }

   }
//.......
}
```

I want to get the **product_id** from the class **SpecificCategoryJSON** and use it in class **ProductDetailsManager** to make a call . What should I do , **inherit** ? **override** ? **UserDefaults.standard.set** ? Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but you should instantiate your `SpecificCategoryJSON` class and access it's property :

```
func printPublicGists() -> Void {
    let url: String = "http://xxx/get_product_informations/"    
    let cat = SpecificCategoryJSON(items: someJSON)

    let parameter = ["product_id": cat.product_id]

    // ....
}
```

Comment: in this case I have to send some value in **items** , but I am not calling any **JSON** response for **SpecificCategoryJSON** in this **class**, thats in other **class**

Comment: So you should find a way to notify **ProductDetailsManager** when a new **items JSON** is available and then instantiate **SpecificCategoryJSON** with it. You could use NSNotifications, KVO or anything else.